# PHP MailChimp integration Lead Capture Form Issue

Tags: php, mailchimp

First time posting, so I apologize in advance if I don't format everything properly, but I'll do my best.

Created a PHP MailChimp integration for a Lead Capture form, and I've been slamming my head against the wall.  The form simply captures the email address of a visitor and sends them to a 'success' page.  That success page thanks them, and redirects them to the main home page after 1 second.

Here's the curious thing.  When I test the setup on my desktop and phone, the leads are properly sent to the MailChimp list via the PHP API script and everything performs perfectly.

I use LuckyOrange to monitor visitor behavior.  The software 'records' visitor sessions (anonymously) so I can watch playbacks.

I've been sending FB traffic to the landing page for the past three hours, and I've watched literally 5-10 people enter their email addresses into the form.  But the leads are not appearing in MailChimp.  On the recordings, the page just seems to refresh after they click 'submit.'

Any ideas?  I don't even know what code might be the culprit, otherwise I'd post a sample.  Just looking for someone to point me in the right direction to figure out what's going on.

Thanks so much for your time.

Best,
John

Comment: If the same exact files work on your desktop, there is probably an error message somewhere. I would find out where PHP logs errors (often a `php_error` file in the same directory as the failing PHP file).  Once you find it, you will get more info about what's going wrong

Comment: Thanks. Waiting for access to the log file. It seems that this might primarily be happening on iPhones / Macs... could the PHP be firing differently on those devices?  Thanks again for your help and time.

Comment: Have you verified this?  That on an iPhone or Mac this specific feature doesn't work, but on a Windows device the same specific feature works?

Comment: Don't have the devices required to personally test - used an online simulator and it went through perfectly.  Not sure how accurate a representation that is, though.

That said, I managed to fix the issue by examining the logs (thank you again for that advice). The lead capture form only has a field for email addresses to maximize conversions; however, the PHP API template I integrated was calling/pushing FNAME and LNAME as well, which were not being captured.  I added placeholder 'first' and 'last' strings into the API script, and instantly the conversion rate jumped up 300-400%. Thank you.

Comment: For anyone reading this that isn't 100% sure where the PHP logs are stored (my situation), simply create a small file called info.php somewhere on the server with this code, then browse to it: <?php phpinfo(); ?>